# geom_vline and scale_x_discrete dont fit with each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a newbie here.

1, The aim is to plot a graph about the mean NDVI value during a time period (8 dates were chosen from 2019-05 to 2019-10) of my study site (named RB1). And plot vertical lines to show the date with a grass cutting event.

2, Now I had calculated the NDVI value for these 8 chosen dates and made a CSV file.
(PS. the "cutting" means when the grassland on the study site has been cut, so the corresponding dates should be show as a vertical line, using geom_vline)

```
infor <- read_csv("plotting information.csv")
infor
# A tibble: 142 x 3
   date         NDVI cutting
   <date>      <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 2019-05-12 NA     NA     
 2 2019-05-13 NA     NA     
 3 2019-05-14 NA     NA     
 4 2019-05-15 NA     NA     
 5 2019-05-16 NA     NA     
 6 2019-05-17  0.787 TRUE      
# ... with 132 more rows
```

3, the problem is, when I do the ggplot, first I want to keep the x-axis as the whole time period (2019-05 to 2019-10) but of course not show all dates in between, otherwise there will be way too much dates show on the x-axis). So, I do the `scale_x_discrte(breaks=, labels=)` to show the specific dates with NDVI values.

Second I also want to show the dates that the grasses were cut `geom_vline`.

BUT, it seems like the precondition for `scale_x_discrte` is to `factor` my date, while the precondition for `geom_vline` is to keep the date as `nummeric`.
 these two calls seems to be contradictory.

```
y1 <- ggplot(infor, aes(factor(date), NDVI, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=infor[!is.na(infor$NDVI),]) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("2019-05-17", "2019-06-18", "2019-06-26", "2019-06-28","2019-07-23","2019-07-28", "2019-08-27","2019-08-30", "2019-09-21"), 
                   labels = c("0517","0618","0626","0628","0723","0728", "0827","0830","0921"))) 


y2 <- ggplot(infor, aes(date, NDVI, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=infor[!is.na(infor$NDVI),]))
```

when I add the geom_vline in the y1, vertical lines do not show on my plot:
[y1 + geom_vline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PR6L.png)

when I add it in the y2, vertical lines were showed, but the dates (x axis) are weird (not show as the y1 because we donot run the scale_x_ here) 
 [y2 + geom_vline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4HaT.png)

```
   y1 + 
      geom_vline(data=filter(infor,cutting == "TRUE"), aes(xintercept = as.numeric(date)), color = "red", linetype ="dashed")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead do two things:

1. Do not factorize date and use scale_x_continuous instead
2. geom_vline can be easily used with numeric x axis